# Connect Blazor WebAssembly to Dataverse with Dataverse ServiceClient

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly, dataverse

Is there a way to access the Microsoft Dataverse ServiceClient from a Blazor WebAssembly app. Or alternatively, another class that implements IOrganisationService?

when i try to connect i get following error:

> ---> Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Utils.DataverseConnectionException: Failed to connect to Dataverse
> ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
> at System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler.set_UseCookies(Boolean value)
> at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_UseCookies(Boolean value)
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Utils.ClientServiceProviders.<>c.b__3_0()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.HttpClientBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__1(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder b)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.g__Configure|0(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder b)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.LoggingHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(HttpMessageHandlerBuilder builder)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandlerEntry(String name)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<.ctor>b__1()
> at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=3.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode) at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=3.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
> at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=3.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1[[Microsoft.Extensions.Http.ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry, Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=3.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].get_Value()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateHandler(String name)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.DefaultHttpClientFactory.CreateClient(String name)
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Auth.AuthProcessor.GetAuthorityFromTargetServiceAsync(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, Uri targetServiceUrl, DataverseTraceLogger logger, Boolean isOnPrem)
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Auth.AuthProcessor.ExecuteAuthenticateServiceProcessAsync(Uri serviceUrl, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, X509Certificate2 userCert, String clientId, Uri redirectUri, PromptBehavior promptBehavior, Boolean isOnPrem, String authority, Object msalAuthClient, DataverseTraceLogger logSink, Boolean useDefaultCreds, SecureString clientSecret, Boolean addVersionInfoToUri, IAccount user, MemoryBackedTokenCache memoryBackedTokenCache, String tokenCacheStorePath)
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.ConnectAndInitServiceAsync(OrganizationDetail orgdata, Boolean IsOnPrem, Uri homeRealmUri)
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.DoDirectLoginAsync(Boolean IsOnPrem)
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.InitServiceAsync()
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.GetCachedService(ConnectionService& ConnectionObject)
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.IntilizeService(ConnectionService& ConnectionObject)
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ConnectionService.DoLogin(ConnectionService& ConnectionObject)
> at Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.ServiceClient.CreateServiceConnection(Object externalOrgServiceProxy, AuthenticationType requestedAuthType, String hostName, String port, String orgName, NetworkCredential credential, String userId, SecureString password, String domain, String Geo, String claimsHomeRealm, Boolean useSsl, Boolean useUniqueInstance, OrganizationDetail orgDetail, String clientId, Uri redirectUri, PromptBehavior promptBehavior, OrganizationWebProxyClientAsync externalOrgWebProxyClient, String certificateThumbPrint, StoreName certificateStoreName, X509Certificate2 certificate, Uri instanceUrl, Boolean isCloned, Boolean useDefaultCreds, Version incomingOrgVersion, ILogger externalLogger, String tokenCacheStorePath)